# IDAPRO from command line interface: Exporting IDB file to BINEXPORT file

Tags: ida, tool-bindiff, ida-plugin

I'm trying to convert my IDB files to BINEXPORT files using the following command that has been advised in many similar questions:

```
    "<path-to-idaq.exe>" -A -OExporterModule:<result-directory> -S"<path-to-export-script>" "<path-to-idb>"
```

However, I get 4 files in return(ID0, ID1, NAM, TIL files) and no BINEXPORT file. Am I on the right path?

(**Edit: I moved my .idb, idc and batch file to another directory and now my .idb file is being rewritten each time I launch the command instead...)**

I think my  file which is a .idc is correct:

```
    #include <idc.idc>

    static main()
    {
         Batch(0);
        Wait();
        Exit(1 - RunPlugin("zynamics_binexport_8", 2));
    }
```

Comment: I can convert idb files by using your command, <br>Try to remove "-A" and observed error messages in IDA window